# Why is the menu of my program stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: python

I'm creating a program so that a track coach can easily pull up runners times as well as input them.

I'm trying to figure out why when I start my program, it runs the function 'MENU', looping it.

```
user_input = 0

print('MENU')
print('1 - Add runner data to file')
print('2 - Display runners and their times')
print('3 - Calculate the average run time')
print('4 - Display the fastest time')
print('5 - EXIT')
print()

def MENU():
    user_input = int(input('Enter your Menu choice >> '))
    return -1

def DATA(f_runner, f_time):
    f_runner = str(input('Enter runners name >> '))
    f_time = str(input('Enter the runners time in hours >> '))
    print('Runners data entered into the file.')
    f = open('myFile.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(f_runner))
    f.write(str(f_time))
    f.close()
    return f_runner, f_time

def DISPLAY():
    contents = f.readlines()
    f = open('myFile.txt')
    print(contents)

runners_data = 0
runner = 0
runner_time = 0
average_time = 0
file_runner = ''
file_time = 0.0
contents = ''
program_exit = False
menu_start = 0

while program_exit == False:
    menu_start = MENU()
    while user_input > 0 and user_input < 6:
        if user_input == '1':
            DATA(file_runner, file_time)
        elif user_input == '2':
            Display()
        elif user_input == '5':
            program_exit = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning -1 instead of user_input in MENU()

Answer (score 0):

Alongside what Samraj said, I believe it's also because your if statement is comparing if the user input is returned as a string, when you're expecting the user to return an int.
You could just remove it from the bottom and have it run inside menu and just call MENU().

Try this and edit it to what you need

```
print('MENU')
print('1 - Add runner data to file')
print('2 - Display runners and their times')
print('3 - Calculate the average run time')
print('4 - Display the fastest time')
print('5 - EXIT')
print()

def MENU():
    the_input = int(input('Enter your Menu choice >> '))
    if the_input == 1:
        print("hello")
        DATA(file_runner, file_time)
    elif the_input == 2:
        Display()
    elif the_input == 5:
        exit()
    return the_input

def DATA(f_runner, f_time):
    f_runner = str(input('Enter runners name >> '))
    f_time = str(input('Enter the runners time in hours >> '))
    print('Runners data entered into the file.')
    f = open('myFile.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(f_runner))
    f.write(str(f_time))
    f.close()
    return f_runner, f_time

def DISPLAY():
    contents = f.readlines()
    f = open('myFile.txt')
    print(contents)

runners_data = 0
runner = 0
runner_time = 0
average_time = 0
file_runner = ''
file_time = 0.0
contents = ''
program_exit = False
menu_start = 0

MENU()
```